# Why were there green Lumin discs above Borg regeneration alcoves and blue ones in random places in Star Trek Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Why were there green Lumin discs above Borg regeneration alcoves and blue ones in random places in Star Trek Voyager? Meaning, did they have an in-universe explanation for them?

These things were popular in every novelty gift shop in the 1990's and can still be found on eBay and Alibaba for $10 - $30. Did someone from the production team just seem them and say "Hey, cool! Let's put those all over the place!" or is there some function they were supposed to be serving?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have answered your own question.  The Star Trek folk thought they looked nicely futuristic so used them for the Borg.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Tim Are you sure? I know they make a lot of books and stuff going over all the technical descriptions of everything in the series. This will be the first case when something this prominent doesn't have a story behind it.

Comment: Oh, there's probably a story behind it.  I can't find any particular reason for them online though.  But I'm certain that they were used due to their futuristic appearance.  But, if you mean to ask what is their in-world purpose, I'd suggest rephrasing your question.

Comment: @Tim OK sure I'll rephrase it a bit, thanks

Comment: Hmm ... "Respond to music" ... that must be a significant bit of information to solve this puzzle.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The caption is from the seller on a Chinese import site

Comment: Memory alpha claims that this component was "Unnecessary to [the alcove's] use" and cites the episode "Dark Frontier." Anyone care to follow up on that?