# Why does the shuttlecraft have what appears to be soundproofing on its walls?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, season 2 episode 17 there are some extended scenes set inside one of the Enterprise's shuttlecraft. In a few shots you can see what appears to be acoustic soundproofing on some sections of the walls.

Here are screenshots from two angles:

[image] [image]

And for comparison a product photo of "Wedge Style Acoustic Foam Panels" from a shopping website:

[image]

It looks like, or at least could be, a similar material. These panels are designed to generally absorb sound and prevent it from being transmitted or reflected, as far as I understand it.

*In-universe* Is it ever explained what purpose these panels serve to the function of the shuttlecraft?

While sound couldn't be transmitted through the vacuum of space, perhaps some mechanism of the shuttle itself required sound dampening for the comfort or safety of the occupants?

And if these aren't soundproofing, what is it for?

---

Note - out of universe this very well could have just been a prop/set design choice. But they chose to film against it very prominently for extended periods which gives the impression it wasn't expected to be a trivial or unnoticed background detail. Star Trek sets typically have lots of well-thought out details that aren't completely random. I'm assuming that was the case here.

Comment: It would appear to be someone's idea of futuristic decorations.

Comment: Because it's very noisy in space.

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/database/acoustic-panels.htm

Comment: @Valorum interesting, so there are a lot more shapes & sizes of these things... thanks

Comment: You know how in space, no-one can hear you scream? That's thanks to consistent high-quality spacecraft design.

Comment: There are other sets where the walls are covered in plastic shipping pallets, because they have visually interesting/busy shapes when viewed from the bottom.

Comment: well thought props? Kidding right? Like the stuff you could buy at Spencer's in any mall in the US in 1992? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145079/why-were-there-green-lumin-discs-above-borg-regeneration-alcoves-and-blue-ones-i

Comment: @NKCampbell so they were "economical" in their materials sourcing :)  But I wasn't kidding in the sense that IMO the set design had a huge influence on the style of the show & the tone many of the scenes had.

Comment: oh I agree - I've got big love for TNG. Another fun real world thing that appears is the centerpiece in Ten-Foward - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pair_Match

Comment: @NKCampbell ha! thanks. I have to explore that website more...

Comment: @NKCampbell - Sure, because modern series' are really different; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125191/20774

Comment: they are all twitch streamers off duty

Comment: It "busies up" what would otherwise be a flat wall. In terms of on-screen appearance, it at least looks like they are in a place and gives the compartment some scale; an empty flat wall takes all that away. From a practical point of view, it probably does work as acoustic damping making it easier to use live sound in the final audio instead of post-production dubbing. As for the specific choice of shape and pattern, it's unfamiliar to most of us, so it works as something futuristic.

Comment: Starfleet also ran fly-to-you recording studios out of their shuttles......;)